# Android Populate ArrayList with visible ListFragment items

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listfragment

I'm using ListFragment in a ViewPager. Is there a way to populate an ArrayList with the visible ListFragment's list items everytime the user pages to a new page?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an (OnPageChangeListener) onPageSelected()  for the ViewPager and use it to detect which page the user has switched too. Then you can use the ListView getLastVisiblePosition and getFirstVisiblePosition to find out which items are currently displayed in the listView. Then it's simply a matter of storing those items in an arraylist.